# Auto refresh backlogs panel when work item change

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, vssdk

I have an advanced capacity planning extension that replace the work details panel in the current iteration back log panel.

is there a way to register to workitem change event? currently thr only event work is the work item selection change event which is not relevant.

thanks
dror

Answer (score 1):

According to your title, you want to enable live updates to automatically refresh your backlogs  when work item changes occur.

This is not available at present. You still have to press F5 to see the latest changes.

There is already a related user voice, kindly upvote it and our PM will review any feature request:

> **Button to refresh the backlog, or ability to auto-refresh backlog**
>
> https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/501639/button-to-refresh-the-backlog-or-ability-to-auto-r.html